# C# PowerShell Add-PowerAppsAccount Net Core Console App error retrieving member WithAuthority

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, powerapps, power-platform

I am getting error `{"The following exception occurred while retrieving member \"WithAuthority\": \"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.\""}` while executing Powershell command `Add-PowerAppsAccount -Username $user -Password $pass` using the following code in a Console App .Net Core 3.1:

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
 ps.AddScript(query);
 ps.AddParameters(prms);
 var pipelineObjects = await ps.InvokeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
 foreach (var item in pipelineObjects)
 {
  if (item != null)
   Console.WriteLine(item.BaseObject.ToString());
  else
   Console.WriteLine("");
 }
}
```

Any ideas and comments will be much appreciated.

**Note 1: The code works correctly in PowerShell 7.0**

**Note 2: This will be an Azure Function in the future.**

Answer (score 0):

Just added this lines to the .csproj file in PropertGroup and it worked.

```
<UseWpf>true</UseWpf>
<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
```